# WordPress htaccess - redirect http to https

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I was wondering if someone could help us out with this one.

We have a site that has lots of insecure links in various pages across the site. Some pages are also including images from http sources and not https.

An example page is here: https://mindfulpresenter.com/mindful-blog/the-10-most-important-things-in-presenting-today/ - on here you will see that there are some links to http pages and the page is sourcing an image from http.

I was hoping that all of these issues can be resolved by making changes to the htaccess file.

The current htaccess file looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Can the issues be resolved by making changes to the htaccess file? If so, what do I need to add to it?

Many thanks

James

Comment: No, that is not possible. The references inside the web pages you deliver are nothing that can be changed by such rules. Those rules only real with _incoming_ requests, so requests already used by the browser.

Comment: arkascha's comment here is not accurate. The module mod_substitute does in fact modify the HTML that is served out to the client. Please see my answer below.

Comment: Do you really want to replace ALL http entries? what about the images that does not exist on HTTPS domains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a ['Search and Replace' plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/) for WordPress which searched the database and replaced all of the HTTP entries.

Comment: But did you really want to replace ALL http entries? what about the images that did not exist on HTTPS domains?

Answer (score 0):

It appears, that the links are in the content of your pages / posts which is stored in the database as text. I recommend doing a search & replace to achieve a "clean" state.

There are some plugins that parse the content and create those links dynamically but i don't think that is the most elegant solution.

Comment: Hi noreabu. Do you know which search and replace code I will need to run in PHPMyAdmin? I believe the http links are in posts and pages so I'll need two scripts I imagine, one for each table in the database?

Comment: Since this is some while ago i do not exactly recall the code.
Probably something like this:

UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'http://secured-domain.foo', 'https://secured-domain.foo')
WHERE post_content LIKE 'http://'

I wrote an domain name since i do not know if you have some links to other pages that will not accept https.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of plugins that may help you. I use [SSL Insecure Content Fixer](https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/ssl-insecure-content-fixer/) on my website and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

You can, in fact, modify the contents of the page as it is being served, using mod_substitute: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_substitute.html

In particular, you'd do something like:

```
Substitute s/src="http:/src="https:/i
```

See the mod_substitute docs for further information and examples.